# acess nested object of json in java

Tags: java, json

This is my JSON file

```
{
    "content": [
    {
        "a":{
            "b" : "abcd",
            "c" : "bcd"
        }
        "ab" : "123",
        "abc":{
            "id" : "12345",
            "name" : "abcde"
        }
        "cd": "afsf"
    },
    {
        "a":{
            "b" : "abcd",
            "c" : "bcd"
        }
        "ab" : "123",
        "abc":{
            "id" : "12345",
            "name" : "abcde"
        }
        "cd": "afsf"
    }
    ]
}
```

I want the `"id"` of object `"abc"` in Java?
I created a object of content and the code is below

```
JSONArray content = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("content");
for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject inner = (JSONObject) content.getJSONObject(i);
            String abc = inner.getString("Loan_Application__r");                
}
```

How to i access now the `"id"` and `"name"` in java?
pls ignore if any syntax mistake is their...

Comment: get inner JSONObject `"abc"` then get its `id` value same way u got the `inner` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the below code as a hint to approach your problem:-

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        String json="{ \"content\": [  {\"a\":{ \"b\" : \"abcd\", \"c\" : \"bcd\"},\"ab\" : \"123\",\"abc\":{\"id\" : \"12345\", \"name\" : \"abcde\"},\"cd\": \"afsf\"},{\"a\":{\"b\" : \"abcd\",  \"c\" : \"bcd\"},\"ab\" : \"123\",\"abc\":{\"id\" : \"12346\",\"name\" : \"abcde\"},\"cd\": \"afsf\"}]}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("content");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject objects = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String[] elementNames = JSONObject.getNames(objects); 

                       for (String elementName : elementNames)
                          {
                           if(elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("abc")){
                           JSONObject value = objects.getJSONObject(elementName);
                           String[] elementList = JSONObject.getNames(value); 
                            for(String j:elementList){
                                if(j.equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
                                System.out.println(value.getString("id"));  
                                }
                            }
                          }
                          }

        }
    }

Output:-
12345
12346
```