# How extract JSONObject from JSONArray in android

Tags: java, android, json

I want to read only the "value" object from this jsonarray

```
"body":{"und":[{"value":"hi friends!!!","summary":null,"format":null}]}
```

This is my code:

```
  protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject result) {



            try {
                TextView lst2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View2);


                JSONArray cast = result.getJSONArray("body");
                for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject actor = cast.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = actor.getString("value");
                    lst2.setText(name);
                }




            } catch (Exception e2) {
                Log.v("Error adding article", e2.getMessage());
            }


    }
```

JSONObject result is the response from the rest server.

Comment: See this example if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092668/acess-nested-object-of-json-in-java/32093501#32093501

Comment: What is/isn't happening in your code? Also, setting the text in a loop like that will only set it to the last value (i.e. whatever is in `cast.getJSONObject(cast.length() -1)`

Comment: "body":{"und":[{"value":"hi friends!!!","summary":null,"format":null}]}   it is invalid jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

body is not array its object, you need to get und out of body as JSONArray first

```
protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject result) {



        try {
            TextView lst2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View2);


            JSONArray cast = result.getJSONObject("body").getJSONArray("und");
            for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject actor = cast.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = actor.getString("value");
                lst2.setText(name);
            }




        } catch (Exception e2) {
            Log.v("Error adding article", e2.getMessage());
        }


}
```

Hope it helps